# Use and preserve a plaintext style attribute in a React component on an HTML node

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, attributes

I know that React wants me to supply a JavaScript object to the `style` attribute in JSX like so:

```
render() { return <p style={{ border: '1px solid black'}}>My text.</p> }
```

However, I have larger portions of inline styles in legacy HTML code that I would rather not refactor just for React; additionally I find it overkill to specifiy all styles in custom variables.

Therefore I'd really use the inline, plaintext `style` attribute just as regular HTML:

```
render() {return <p style="border: 1px solid black;">My text.</p> }
```

Can this be done in React at all or is there no way to use the HTML-like way?

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible. You could build a (relatively simple) converter though.

Comment: Not possible, no. There are converters however you can use, such as [this one](http://facebook.github.io/react/html-jsx.html)

Comment: If I recall correctly, I think I had read somewhere that a long-term plan was to have this work in a future update.